# Shell Script with If, Select and Case

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Can anyone advise how to edit this script to perform the following:

If folder exists - "then are you sure you want to uninstall?"
If yes - perform file copying, if not then stop script.
Else - can't find folder, stop script.

```
if [ -e "/tmp/installpackage" ]
then
    echo "Are you sure you want to uninstall?"
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
            Yes ) 
                echo "Beginning uninstall...";
                cp file1.txt original/path/location;
                break;;
            No ) 
                echo "Stopping uninstall.";
                exit 1;;
        esac
    done
else
    echo "Can't find the folder, package not isntalled."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Did you try with a "read" command? It's easier and more readable.

Comment: What's the problem with your script? It looks like it does what you want it to.

Comment: I've tried a few methods at this stage.  My script goes through a continuous entry loop and won't actually do anything that I've coded for.

Comment: Don't you just want `break` once, before `done`?

Comment: This is a modified script, that I found online, to which I've inserted it inside an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works as expected. But you have to enter `1` or `2` and not `yes` or `no`.

However I would change the first line to:

```
if [ -d "/tmp/installpackage" ]
```

`-d` tests whether the file exists **and** is a directory

Comment: Actually the expression after `case` does not require quoting.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah this makes sense. (As long as the value list just contains just "yes" and "no"). However, quoting vars is a good practice. Better do it one more than one less - if this won't break anything

Answer (score 0):

I think after the line `esac` you want a `exit` otherwise you have a infinite loop to ask you for answers

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if [ -d "/tmp/installpackage" ]
then
    echo "Are you sure you want to uninstall?"
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $REPLY in
            Yes ) 
                echo "Beginning uninstall...";
                cp file1.txt original/path/location;
                break;;
            No ) 
                echo "Stopping uninstall.";
                exit 1;;
            *)
                echo "Incorrect choice";
                break;;
        esac
    done
else
    echo "Can't find the folder, package not installed."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try testing for bail out conditions first then fall through to the uninstall code:

```
[ ! -d '/tmp/installpackage' ] && \
echo "Can't find the folder, package not isntalled." && exit 1

echo -n 'Are you sure you want to uninstall? [y|n] '
read answer
[[ ! "$answer" = [Yy] ]] && echo 'Stopping uninstall.' && exit 1

echo 'Beginning uninstall...'
cp file1.txt original/path/location
```